# response listener not working correctly

Tags: php, android

i have a register activity and a login activity i want to open login activity when user successfully register.but in my case i am not getting login activity after registration. user register successfully in data base table.
here is the code of response listener.

```
private void registerUser(final String name, final String email,
                          final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_register";

    pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response);
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);

                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                if (!error) {
                    // User successfully stored in MySQL
                    // Now store the user in sqlite


                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String name = user.getString("name");
                    String email = user.getString("email");
                    String created_at = user
                            .getString("created_at");

                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.addUser(name, email,  created_at);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User successfully registered. Try login now!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    // Launch login activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            RegisterActivity.this,
                            LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {

                    // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                    // message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("name", name);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

- 2 php code

  ```
  <?php
      require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';

      $db = new DB_Functions();

      $response = array("error" => FALSE);


      if (isset($_REQUEST['name']) && isset($_REQUEST['email']) && isset($_REQUEST['password'])) {


       // receiving the REQUEST params
          $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
          $email = $_REQUEST['email'];

        $password = $_REQUEST['password'];

          if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {

              $response["error"] = TRUE;

           $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed with " . $email;

          echo json_encode($response);

        } else {

       $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);

        if ($user) {

           $response["error"] = FALSE;


             $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];

            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];

           $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];

            $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];

           echo json_encode($response);

        } else {

             $response["error"] = TRUE;

           $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";

              echo json_encode($response);

          }
          }
      } else {

        $response["error"] = TRUE;

        $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters (name, email or password) is missing!";

        echo json_encode($response);
      }
  ?>
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
## Write the Intent this way ##
Intent intent = new Intent(
                        RegisterActivity.this,
                        LoginActivity.class);
              RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```